# Is there no difference between function and objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In the book [Javascript: The good parts](http://bdcampbell.net/javascript/book/javascript_the_good_parts.pdf) the author uses following code to create objects

```
 if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
 Object.create = function (o) {
 var F = function () {};
 F.prototype = o;
 return new F();
 };
 }
 var another_stooge = Object.create(stooge);
```

The function is meant to create an object but it returns a function instead.
(Reference - Chapter 3, Page number : 22)

Comment: How are you determining that it returns a function? Because `Object.create` returns a new instance of the object passed into it.

Comment: All functions in JavaScript *are* objects.

Comment: Just as Marcus said, all functions are objects but not all objects are functions. Objects created with literal syntax are not functions. And now with ES6 we have Class which obviously is not a function.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan `Object.creare` returns `F()` which is a function

Comment: No, it returns `new F()`. Please read [the documentation for Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) and the [new keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Ok, so `new F()` returns an object with prototype `o`.

Comment: @Burimi: Actually, `class` does create functions :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there no difference between function and objects in javascript?

Functions are objects that can be called, and they're created with different syntax.

> The author uses following code to create objects […]

We should no more. [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) is standardised and implemented in about every browser.

Anyway, we should not try to understand what `Object.create` does by looking at this horrible polyfill. We should treat `Object.create` as a langauge primitive (and we can define the `new` operator in terms of it if we want).

> The function is meant to create an object but it returns a function instead.

No, it doesn't. It does not return `F`, it does `return new F()`, which is the result of a **call** to `F` (as a constructor).